# Как правильно сделать рефакторинг Exceptions

Tags: java

Подскажите, как правильно сделать рефакторинг Exceptions. Например вынести в отдельный метод и тп. На разных сайтах все пишут по-разному. Направьте в нужное русло ссылочкой на stackoverflow или еще какой ответ.

Например есть такой код. Я хочу, вынести в отдельный класс. После того, как вынесу в отдельный класс, наверно надо разделить его на методы. В общем явно такая конструкция в 1 методе врятли будет правильной. Покажите, как запихнуть / разделить такую массивную конструкцию, чтобы она была в методе и в то же время не выглядело, как быдло-код.

```
try {
//...

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //...

} catch (IOException e) {
//...

} finally {
    try {
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            //...

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //...

        }
}
```

Comment: @Одиннадцать Комментариев, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Одиннадцать Комментариев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Конечно надо уметь и учиться писать красиво и компактно, но есть места где без нагромождений не обойтись.

Отлов эксепшенов - совершенно нормальное дело и никуда это не уберешь. Вот например код из исходников разработчиков библиотеки [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

```
@Override public void run() {
    try {
      updateThreadName(data);

      if (picasso.loggingEnabled) {
        Utils.log(Utils.OWNER_HUNTER, Utils.VERB_EXECUTING, Utils.getLogIdsForHunter(this));
      }

      result = hunt();

      if(data.justMeasure){
          if(imageWidth != 0 && imageHeight != 0){
              dispatcher.dispatchComplete(this);
          } else {
              dispatcher.dispatchFailed(this);
          }
      } else {
          if (result == null) {
              dispatcher.dispatchFailed(this);
          } else {
              dispatcher.dispatchComplete(this);
          }
      }
    } catch (Downloader.ResponseException e) {
      exception = e;
      dispatcher.dispatchFailed(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      exception = e;
      dispatcher.dispatchRetry(this);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      stats.createSnapshot().dump(new PrintWriter(writer));
      exception = new RuntimeException(writer.toString(), e);
      dispatcher.dispatchFailed(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      exception = e;
      dispatcher.dispatchFailed(this);
    } finally {
      Thread.currentThread().setName(Utils.THREAD_IDLE_NAME);
    }
  }
```

Как видно всё обработано и при нормальном форматировании смотрится сносно.

Кстати еще Java >= 7 можно объединять экспешены

```
catch(Exception1 | Exception2 | Exception3 e)
{
}
```

Прошу прощения за сумбур, но в целом наверное я донёс то, что хотел сказать :)

Comment: получается, если я закину 1 большой try целиком в 1 метод это не будет дурным тоном?

Comment: Смотря сколько логических блоков выполняете в методе. По-хорошему чем меньше метод делает тем лучше. Но например если в одном методе идет сначала чтение файла, а затем из считанной информации что-то выбирается, то тут можно читать файл в одном блоке и при возникновении исключения сообщить о проблеме чтения файла, а во втором блоке при исключении сообщить о неверном формате данных в файлу. Try и catch сделаны для того, чтобы программа аварийно не завершалась и все ошибки обрабатывались и сообщали пользователю или системе о проблеме.